# How to update a field from an access database table with the number of records from another table?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, count

I am having a hard time finding a way to count the number of times a record from a table appears in another table. What I am trying to achieve is having a column in my first table that updates every time a new record is introduced in my second table, keeping count of how many instances of data appear from my first table into my seond.

[image]

So what I am trying to achieve is having nr_modele from Utilizatori_designer keep track pf how many times the id From Utilizatori_designer appears in the field creator from Modele

Comment: This goes against database normalization principles - any value that can easily be calculated should not be stored in a table, but rather calculated as required.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same in a PostGreSQL database, simplifying  the table - I'm on Linux and have no Access database

The example tables:

```
CREATE TABLE modele ( id, nume_model,creator) AS (
          SELECT 1,'Kadett'  ,42
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Admiral' ,42
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'Rekord'  ,42
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'Omega'   ,42
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'Blitz'   ,42
UNION ALL SELECT 6,'Kapitaen',42
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'Mondeo'  ,43
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Model T' ,43
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'Galaxy'  ,43
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'Taunus'  ,43
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'Cortina' ,43
UNION ALL SELECT 6,'GT'      ,43
);

CREATE TABLE utilizatori_designer(id,nume,nr_modele) AS (
          SELECT 42,'Opel',CAST(NULL AS INTEGER)
UNION ALL SELECT 43,'Ford',CAST(NULL AS INTEGER)
);
```

The table `utilizatori_designer` now contains:

```
 id | nume | nr_modele 
----+------+-----------
 42 | Opel |    (null)
 43 | Ford |    (null)
```

Then, I update just the row for `'Opel`' for the `nr_modele` column:

```
UPDATE utilizatori_designer
SET nr_modele = (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM modele
  WHERE creator = utilizatori_designer.id
)
WHERE id=42;
```

And I get:

```
 id | nume | nr_modele 
----+------+-----------
 43 | Ford |    (null)
 42 | Opel |         6
```